# Как сделать запрос к другому сайту в Django?

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно получить json или csv по ссылке с другого сайта. Как это правильно сделать в django? В обычном случае я пользовался бы библиотекой requests, нужно ли использовать что-то другое?

Comment: Нет, так же используйте requests.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev окей, спасибо